# How can I convert Double Date to std::string

Tags: c++

I got the Date value from the method from the following code

```
  DATE dDate;
  hr = pADsUser->get_PasswordLastChanged(&dDate);
  //   pADsUser is pointer variable of   IADsUser
```

Date type is discribed in the link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82ab7w69%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

How can I convert this kind of Date to string so that I can print it in console.

I am not using MFC Dlls for this application. so I cannot use the COleDateTime type also.

Is there any built in method available or Do I need to calculate the date manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into Boost.Lexical_cast for conversion to and from string.

You will have to write a converter function that unpacks the DATE type into a (date, time) tuple so that lexical_cast won't convert from double.

According to the doc, it looks like the date type is (day - 1899-12-30) . (time - 0).

Using boost::date_time, you can create a time object with date-time (1899-12-30,0), then increment `days(abs(DATE))` and `hours((DATE - abs(DATE)) * 24)`.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. The main challenge part is to find Date value like (11 01 1985) from the Date type specified. How can I change to the date format like( 11 01 1985).

Comment: Answer edited to include how to use Boost.Date_Time in order to make use of the DATE type.

Comment: @Prabhu You can use `gmtime_r` `strftime`, but be warned that time_t is seconds from `1970-Jan-01 00:00:00 UTC+0000`, not days from `1899-12-30`. It's also prone to Y2038 on some 32-bit systems. Your best bet is to use an existing date library to convert day offset to a date structure, then print fields of said structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
TCHAR *strDate = new TCHAR[12];
tm * ptm = gmtime ( &ttAppClosing );
int day = ptm->tm_mday;
int month = ptm->tm_mon+1;
int year = ptm->tm_year;

CString sDay = L"";
sDay.Format(L"%d", day);
if(day < 9)
    sDay.Format(L"0%d", day);

CString sMonth = L"";
sMonth.Format(L"%d", month);
if(month < 9)
    sMonth.Format(L"0%d", month);

_stprintf(strDate, L"%s-%s-%d", sDay, sMonth, 1900 + year);

CString sCloseDate(strDate);
```

Comment: That's very welcome to add a minor explanation on what's being done.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the underlying API then? Linking with Boost can be costly if you're counting bytes :P

```
DATE d;
CComBSTR bstr;
VarBstrFromDate(d, lcid, dwFlags, &bstr);
```

Comment: The OP explicitly told us `I am not using MFC Dlls for this application. so I cannot use the COleDateTime type also.` -> hence this answer seems to be missing a point.